# How to setup remote php on my server?

Tags: php, web-applications, webserver, remote-access

I made a PHP based webapp and a customer of my needs it on his website. Now I want to put the PHP code on my server and let the customer's website include it remotely. How do I set this up? And can I restrict the acces when the customer doesn't need the app anymore and is it secure?

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing such as `remote PHP`. Doesn't work that way. However you can setup some API to communicate between the two servers on backend. You'd still need both servers to be capable of this interaction, that means both servers still need to be fully functional. And if your code on client's server can talk to your API on host server, then they can take that code and see how it interacts with your host and replicate it.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple solution would be to put the PHP-generated content from your website in an `<iframe>` on their website.

Comment: @Downvoter would you care to comment? I think this is a valid answer to a somewhat bogus question.

Comment: I tend to agree, it is a possible solution

Comment: You can't restrict the customer's access to the app like this, since the `<iframe>` would be on their end.

Comment: Actually the `<iframe>` is on the client's web browser, so you would restrict access as you would with any normal login-based system. The OP has given us no indication of what the application is or how it is used. It is plausible that the OP's service would provide all of the end-user authentication, and simply be "branded" to look like the middle-man customer's website. (I'm picturing a web-timesheet service, that "lives" on the customer company's intranet page.)

Comment: Fair enough, that does make sense on second reading now. I think I need more coffee. It was probably the "put ... in an `<iframe>` on their website" that got me, since somehow my brain went "isn't the client the one who decides how the page should look?"

Comment: Of course, I could be totally wrong, and the OP needs a webservice like Hanky Panky's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18735053/119527). It's hard to tell with the limited amount of information he has given us. I was just offering a keep-it-simple alternative.